# how to design like this form in html

Tags: html, css

Hi in the below image how to display same like that design using html css. This is sample HTML code. How to display ..... lines in HTML?

Can any one please help me

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="contactus">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="contact-page">

                <h2>Contact Us</h2>
<hr>
                    <img src="images/contactus.jpg"/>
                                      <p class="right"> <b>Address:</b>D-000, Text Text , Text . Text ,<br>
Text (Text ), Text -000 000, Text <br>
<b>Mobile :</b>+91- 000-000-0000 <br>
<b>Phone:</b>+ 0000 0000 0000 <br>
<b>Fax:</b>+ 0000 0000 0000 <br>
<b>Email Us </b>abc@gmail.com / abc@gmail.com</p>


                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
                 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap would be easy ;) otherwise you can use tables to display it this way, with 3 columns... One with the image, 1 for labels, 1 for inputs

Comment: can you give me some example

Comment: Do you use bootstrap?

Comment: yes I am using bootstrap

Comment: Posted answer to show you how you could do the job with bootstrap classes ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83273/discussion-between-care567-and-julo0ss).

Comment: let's finish this, what's the matter now? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using bootstrap :

```
<div id='mainContainer' class='col-lg-12'>
    <div id='imageContainer' class='col-lg-4'>
        <!-- ADD YOUR IMAGE HERE -->
    </div>
    <div id='formContainer' class='col-lg-8'>
        <form class='form-horizontal'>
            <div class='col-lg-12 form-group'>
                <label class='col-lg-3 control-label'>ADDRESS : </label>
                <div class='col-lg-9'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ADD THE OTHER INPUTS HERE -->
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not valid code, this is just to show you how you could do this with bootstrap classes.

This should do the job quite as you want it to be : http://www.bootply.com/58yOMmsXhz

EDIT :

here is the "complete sample" of what you're asking. Code still not valid, inputs have no name, form has no attributes, ... But this is the design (with bootstrap) that you're asking :

```
<div id="mainContainer" class="col-lg-12">
    <div id="imageContainer" class="col-lg-4">
        <img src="http://olisvell.com/responsivedesign/images/contactus.jpg" alt="image" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div id="formContainer" class="col-lg-8">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Address : </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" /><br/>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Mobile : </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Phone : </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Fax : </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email Us : </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Connect with us : </label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/Fh0bUmpogs

Hope it helps!

Comment: see my website link after using your codehttp://olisvell.com/responsivedesign/contact.html

Comment: lol, sure it's not working! you have to add the other inputs in the code man...^^ let me edit the code to show you ;)

Comment: @care567 Code edited You have to click on "Run" on bootply ;)

Comment: How to move image to little bit left side

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Image is on the left side already... If you want to change its position just add it some margin or change container text-align to center or something...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83192/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-care567).

Answer (score 0):

That's just an easy approach but it does what you want I guess.

```css
.image
{
  float: left;
  
}

.labels
{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.inputs
{
  float: left;  
}
```

```html
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-318-307-3.jpg" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="labels">
      <strong>Address:</strong><br />
      <strong>Mobile:</strong><br />
      <strong>Address:</strong><br />
      <strong>Mobile:</strong><br />
    </div>
    
    <div class="inputs">
      <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="mobile" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="address" /><br />
      <input type="text" name="mobile" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

follow below link for how to create form
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-g-318-307-3.jpg" />
</div>
<form class="form">
   <ul class="labels">
      <li><label>Address:</label><input type="text" name="address" /></li>
      <li><label>Mobile:</label><input type="text" name="mobile" /></li>
      <li><label>Phone:</label><input type="text" name="address" /></li>
      <li><label>Fax:</label><input type="text" name="mobile" /></li>
      <li><label>Connect with us:</label><input type="text" name="mobile" /></li>
   </ul>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.image , .form
{
  float: left; 
}
.labels
{
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-left:20px;
}
.labels li{
  margin:10px 0;
}
.labels label{
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
}
input[type="text"]
{
  display:inline-block;
  border: 0 none;
  width:300px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `border-bottom: 1px dashed black;`, you get the lines.

Thanks to JLow for the snippet.

```css
.container {
  width: 800px;
}
.image {
  float: left;
}
.labels {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.inputs {
  float: left;
}
.inputs input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}
.inputs input:focus {
  background: #fefefe;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/city" />
  </div>

  <div class="labels">
    <label for="address">Address:</label>
    <br />
    <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label>
    <br />
    <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <br />
    <label for="city">City:</label>
    <br />
  </div>

  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" />
  </div>
</div>
```